# How to add rows to a GXT grid

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

I'm trying to create a fairly simply GWT app using the GXT framework, and am doing this based on the eBook "Ext GWT 2.0 Beginners Guide". It details all the step for building an app using GXTs MVC model, and most of it is working as expected, however I can not - for the life of it - add new rows to my Grid.

The initial loading of the Grid data (through itemStore, loader, and an RPCProxy work correct).

However every time I fire the event that triggers adding a new row, the ListStore to which I want to add, is empty (not null! but empty) - even though my Grid is showing data after the initial load!

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
public class MessageGrid extends LayoutContainer {
    private final Grid<ModelData> grid;
    private final ListLoader<ListLoadResult<MarketingMessage>> loader;
    private final ListStore<ModelData> itemStore;
    public MessageGrid() {
        setLayout(new FitLayout());
        final MarketingServiceAsync marketingService = Registry.get(MarketingUIConstants.MARKETING_SERVICE);
        RpcProxy<List<MarketingMessage>> proxy = new RpcProxy<List<MarketingMessage>>() {
            @Override
            protected void load(Object loadConfig, final AsyncCallback<List<MarketingMessage>> callback) {
                marketingService.getMessages(callback);
            }
        };
        final List<ColumnConfig> columns = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
        columns.add(new ColumnConfig("col1", "Name", 100));
        columns.add(new ColumnConfig("col2", "Phone", 100));
        final ColumnModel columnModel = new ColumnModel(columns);       
        loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<MarketingMessage>>(proxy);
        itemStore = new ListStore<ModelData>(loader);
        grid = new Grid<ModelData>(itemStore, columnModel);
        grid.setBorders(true);
        grid.setAutoExpandColumn("sentTime");
        grid.setAutoHeight(false);
        grid.setHeight("100%");     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        loader.load();
        add(grid);
    }

    public void addMessage(MarketingMessage marketingMessage) {
        itemStore.add(new MarketingMessage("test", "test")));
    }
}
```

addMessage() is being called by the owning component (a View to which this LayoutContainer has been added).

If I set a breakpoint inside the addMessage() method, my itemStore has size 0 (same goes for grid.getStore() for that matter).

I've tried various different changes to this code and I have yet to see a row being added.

On a similar note: if inside the addMessage() method I try to do a reload from the proxy - since I do update the server side data as well - ie. loader.load(), it *also* does not have any visible effect.

Answer (score 1):

The loader is going to be asynchronous - it needs to wait for the server (MarketingService) to return values. Are you certain that this is returning a non-empty list? Verify this by replacing the callback in your proxy with your own callback that checks the contents returned to the client (it may not even be called at all if the server threw an exception).

If addMessage is called onRender or shortly thereafter, it may be too early, and the server may not have returned data yet, so the store may still be empty. If called from a button click or something, this won't be an issue.

Check your log for exceptions, you are passing a Proxy that handles a List of items to a Loader that expects a ListLoadResult - this could also be a source of errors. The confusing generics in GXT 2 should mostly be resolved in 3, which is currently in beta.

Comment: The Loader is functioning and populating the grid. It's not until the app has loaded, and the Grid is displaying existing records from the MarketingService that I click on a (test) button, which in turn triggers a call to addMessage(). So I can't imagine this is related what you just mentioned.

Comment: Ok - it was hard to tell from what was provided. If the grid has items visible, then the store still has items (even though the addMessage call sees no items), which suggests that perhaps the wrong store is being used - perhaps even the wrong instance of MessageGrid. Easy way to verify - step into addMessage, and make sure this.grid.attached is true. If it is, then somehow you've either traded grids, stores, or have found a way to clear the grid without drawing the changes.

Comment: I just checked... grid.attached is showing as false while stepping through the addMessage() method.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Colin, your comment of "you've either traded grids" made me think and then I realize when i set a breakpoint in the constructor it's being hit twice! :-) So this has something to do with the way the overarching MVC model around it is initializing all the pieces, it's somehow creating 2 Grids.